# How to read .pfm files provided with Middlebury dataset?

Tags: python, file, endianness

Dataset is here : http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2014/

PFM file desciption is here : http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/NETPBM/doc/pfm.html

And I'm trying to read file according to description with following code:

```
      header = file.readline().rstrip()
      if header == 'PF':
        color = True    
      elif header == 'Pf':
        color = False
      else:
        raise Exception('Not a PFM file.')

      dim_match = re.match(r'^(\d+)\s(\d+)\s$', file.readline())
      if dim_match:
        width, height = map(int, dim_match.groups())
      else:
        raise Exception('Malformed PFM header.')

      scale = float(file.readline().rstrip())
      if scale < 0: # little-endian
        endian = '<'
        scale = -scale
      else:
        endian = '>' # big-endian
      data = np.fromfile(file, endian + 'f')
      shape = (height, width, 3) if color else (height, width)
      return np.reshape(data, (shape[0]-1, shape[1])), scale
```

But end up with quite strange values in my array. This is just one variant of what I tried to read it, but never get results that looks right. So if someone will help to understand how to read those files correctly, that would be great.

I'm using Windows with Python 2.7.11

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import re

def read_pfm(file):
        # Adopted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809433/read-pfm-format-in-python
        with open(file, "rb") as f:
            # Line 1: PF=>RGB (3 channels), Pf=>Greyscale (1 channel)
            type = f.readline().decode('latin-1')
            if "PF" in type:
                channels = 3
            elif "Pf" in type:
                channels = 1
            else:
                sys.exit(1)
            # Line 2: width height
            line = f.readline().decode('latin-1')
            width, height = re.findall('\d+', line)
            width = int(width)
            height = int(height)

            # Line 3: +ve number means big endian, negative means little endian
            line = f.readline().decode('latin-1')
            BigEndian = True
            if "-" in line:
                BigEndian = False
            # Slurp all binary data
            samples = width * height * channels;
            buffer = f.read(samples * 4)
            # Unpack floats with appropriate endianness
            if BigEndian:
                fmt = ">"
            else:
                fmt = "<"
            fmt = fmt + str(samples) + "f"
            img = unpack(fmt, buffer)
        return img, height, width

    depth_img, height, width = read_pfm(gt_img)
        depth_img = np.array(depth_img)
        # Convert from the floating-point disparity value d [pixels] in the .pfm file to depth Z [mm]
        depths = baseline * focal_length / (depth_img + doffs)
        depths = np.reshape(depths, (height, width))
        depths = np.fliplr([depths])[0]
        plt.imshow(depths)
        plt.show()

I know, I am super late on this. This just works fine.
```

Comment: I think you forgot to mention the `re` (_regular expression_) and `np` (numpy) packages needed to run this function. as well as the `unpack` which is undefined.
You may want to add them in order to have a working solution :)